# Error when using the python module numba

Tags: python, numpy, clang, llvm, numba

I have installed **LLVM 3.2** and all dependencies of **numba** (except Meta):

- LLVM 3.1 or 3.2
- llvmpy (from llvmpy/llvmpy fork)
- llvmmath
- numpy (version 1.6 or higher)
- Meta (from numba/Meta fork (optional))
- Cython (build dependency only)
- nose (for unit tests)
- argparse (for pycc)

I installed LLVM 3.2 and llvmpy according to the instructions on this page https://github.com/llvmpy/llvmpy. All the other python modules were installed using **pip**:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade module_name
```

Next I tried the numba examples on this page: http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/24/numba-vs-cython/. I stored both `pairwise_python` and `pairwise_numba` in a file named `performance.py`. Then when I run

```
from performance import *
```

in IPython I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c7c496c26b18> in <module>()
----> 1 import performance

/home/carlos/Workspace/Freestyle/Numba/performance.py in <module>()
     14             D[i, j] = np.sqrt(d)
     15 
---> 16 @jit(arg_types=[double[:,:], double[:,:]])
     17 def pairwise_numba(X, D):
     18     M = X.shape[0]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numba/decorators.pyc in _jit_decorator(func)
    209             argtys = restype.args
    210         elif argtys is None:
--> 211             assert func.__code__.co_argcount == 0, func
    212             return_type = None
    213             argtys = []

AssertionError: <function pairwise_numba at 0x4b61a28>
```

And I am not able to use pairwise_python nor pairwise_numba. How can I get this to work?

**System information**

- Linux Mint 13 KDE, 64 bit
- Default gcc compiler version: 4.8
- Python 2.7.3 (compiled with gcc 4.6.3)
- LLVM 3.2 (compiled with gcc 4.8)
- llvmpy 0.11.2
- llvmmath 0.1.1
- numpy 1.7.1
- cython 0.19.1
- nose 1.3.0
- argparse 1.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are passing the wrong arguments to `@jit`, try using:

```
@autojit
def yourfunction(...):
    ...
```

If you give more details about your function we can tell you what is wrong with your `@jit` statement.

Comment: Using `@autojit` actually worked. However it should work also in the manner I posted above as it was used for a benchmark in the link I have given above.